# JAVA - Double split string and convert to integer

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, integer

Hello i tried many ways to complete this but i failed.
Could you help me ?
I need double split one is "\n" and second is "|".
In textArea is string 
350|450\n
444|452\n
and so one.
There are mouse coordinates.
X|Y
in int array i need

```
array[0]= x coord;
array[1]= y coord;
array[2]= x coord;
array[2]= y coord;
```

So i have string in textarea.I split that by "\n"

```
String s[]= txtArea.getText().split("\\n");
```

This is one split and in textarea i have something like 150|255 
this is my mouse coordinates x|y.
So i need next split "|".

```
String s2[] = s[i].split("|");
```

After that

```
int [] array = new [s.length*2];
```

And some method for

```
while(!(s[j].equals("|")))
array[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[j]);
```

I tried something like that-

```
for(String line : txtArea.getText().split("\\n")){
            arrayXY = line.split("\\|");
            array = new int[arrayXY.length];
        }
```

Thank you a lot for answers :)
Have a nice day.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here ?? you need  a result array which contains only the x and y coordinates ?

Comment: yes as i show in example arr[0] -x coord; arr[1] - y coord;

Comment: then @paul already gave you the best possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved easily using regex:

```
String[] split = input.split("\\||\n");
```

split will then contain the single numbers from the input.

Comment: and after that how  how do i know if number was one digit or more digit ?

Comment: if (number>9) then its a two digit number

Comment: no i mean mouse coord can be 0|356 or 22|0 or 456|478
how can i know it

Comment: pretty simple, since the numbers are still strings after the split: `if(split[i].length() > 1)itsATwoDigitNumber();`

Comment: Thank you Paul i am done with this and it is working 
Thank you a lot :)
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It is always preferred over [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Your code would then reduce to:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txtArea.getText());
scanner.useDelimiter("\\||\\n");          // i.e. | and the new line
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  // or use the structure you need
    array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Also, don't forget to `import java.util.Scanner;`